# Find Outlook Contacts from code where FullNAme like "Name"

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office

Writing Outlook 2010 AddIn in c#

How to find contacts where for example FullName like "Name"

First I tried

```
string filter = "[FullName] = 'Name'";
```

and it works fine but only for the Name, but now I need to find contacts where FullName can be JonName or Peter Pen or ...

As I uinderstood I should use spacial query string in filter, but what to write?

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder folderContacts;
Outlook.Items contactItems;
Outlook.ContactItem contact;

folderContacts = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.
         GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

contactItems = folderContacts.Items;

string filter = "What should I write here?"; 
var foundContacts = contactItems.Find(filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147590%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

```
string filter = "[FullName] ci_startswith  'Name'";
```

However, I highly recommend that you [use the VSTO Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263100.aspx#id0100108) (free [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=46B6BF86-E35D-4870-B214-4D7B72B02BF9&displaylang=en)) instead; they will make your life much easier.

Comment: string filter = "[FullName] ci_startswith 'Name'"; catch an exaption that it's impossible to analise, error in ci_startswith

I tried to install VSTO Power Tools but installer say that can't find VS2008 - I use VS2010 

What do do?